# Is it possible to access facebook account from 3rd party software?

Tags: facebook, api

I want to write an Android app that given Facebook credentials logs in behalf of the Facebook user and writes on someone else's wall.

Does Facebook API permit this kind of thing? Is it possible to write 3rd party software that does this kind of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> given Facebook credentials

No, but Facebook has even better features, removing the need for passwords.

It has a massive API that allows you to do pretty much anything. https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: just wanted to know if this feature is possible before i start digging in. so you say i can do almost anything from the outside that i would be able to do directly from the website ?